# Multiple draggable droppable and sortable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter-2

I checked these:

[Jquery draggable/droppable and sortable combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118853/jquery-draggable-droppable-and-sortable-combined)

[jQuery UI: sortable and draggable + sortable and droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141723/jquery-ui-sortable-and-draggable-sortable-and-droppable)

[JQuery Draggable + Droppable + Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406258/jquery-draggable-droppable-sortable)

So, answers are none of these.

**Theory**

- I have 2 elements, UL and OL.
- List items of UL has to go in OL
- OL is sortable

**Problem**

- I have multiple such UL and OL on single page.
- I need to make sure that List Items of a UL does not enter OL of other section.

**What have you tried ?**

```
$(function() {
$( ".fetchedfromdb li" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        drag: function(){
            $(".sortintodb ol").droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
                }
        }).sortable({
            sort: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
            }
        });
        }
});
});
```

**My COdeIgniter part:**

```
<?php
echo form_open('/data/process');
echo form_label('yep') . form_textarea('remarks');
foreach($dataFetched as $data => $field) {
    echo "<h2>$data</h2> \n <ul class='fetchedfromdb'>";
        foreach($field as $f):
            $fieldFetch = $data.'_1_1';
            echo '<li>'.$f->$fieldFetch.'</li>';
            echo "<br />";
        endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<div style="background-color: #c3c3c3; height:100px">';
    echo "<ol class=\"sortintodb\" id=\"$data\">";
    echo '<li class="placeholder">Drop here</li>
    </ol>
    </div><hr />';
}
echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_close();
?>
```

via CSS I have made sure that every output till parent foreach ends comes under same section

Any ideas about how can this be implemented?

Any help, much appreciated. Thank you :)

'Visual' representation of what we are looking at...

[image: Isolated multiple drag and drop with sort]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Working demo. [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UMeHU/3/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class='fetchedfromdb' id="da1"> //parent element
    <li id="1">Data1</li>
    <br />
    <li id="2">Data2</li>
    <br />
    <li id="3">Data3</li>
    <br />
<div style="background-color: #c3c3c3; height:100px">
    <ol class="sortintodb" id="e201">
        <li class="placeholder" id="9">Drop here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</ul>//ends

<hr />
<h2>e202</h2> 
<ul class='fetchedfromdb'>
    <li id="5">Data1</li>
    <br />
    <li id="6">Data2</li>
    <br />
    <li id="7">Data4</li>
    <br />
<div style="background-color: #c3c3c3; height:100px">
    <ol class="sortintodb" id="e202">
        <li class="placeholder" id="8">Drop here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</ul>
<hr />
```

**Script**

```
$(".fetchedfromdb li").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        helper: "clone",
        connectToSortable: '.sortable',
    });
    $(".sortintodb").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        //if you don't want same "data" in placeholder more than once
        self.find(".sortintodb").remove();
        var dropId = ui.draggable.attr('id');
        if (self.find("[id=" + dropId + "]").length) return;
        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "id": dropId
        }).appendTo(this);
    },
    });
    $('.sortintodb').sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check this updated fiddle and let me know if any extra behavior required

- added 'empty' class to lists so they can acts as drop target when empty and some visual styles can be applied

http://jsfiddle.net/a8BAY/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable().disableSelection();

    $( ".draggable li" ).draggable({
        revert: true
    });     

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var el = $('<li></li>').text($(ui.draggable).text()).appendTo($(this)); 


            if($(ui.draggable).parent().find('li').size() == 1)
                $(ui.draggable).parent().addClass('empty');
            else
                $(ui.draggable).parent().removeClass('empty');

            $(ui.draggable).remove();

            if($(this).find('li').size() == 1)
                $(this).addClass('empty');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('empty');

            if($(this).is('.sortable')) {
                $(this).sortable( "refresh" );
                $(this).sortable( "refreshPositions" );             
            } else {
                $(el).draggable({
                    revert: true
                });     
            }

        },
        accept: function(draggable) {
            return $(draggable).parent().data('section') == $(this).data('section') && !$(draggable).parent().is($(this));              
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Fixed issue related to placeholder element for sortable http://jsfiddle.net/a8BAY/4/

Answer (score 0):

so i am guessing you want to have some code that updates the database on what you have ordered/dropped?

in your jquery .drop & .sort functions have some code that runs a jquery ajax to post the data to the controller.  the controller can then get your model to re-order the data to mimic what is shown on the screen.

below is code i used to do this as an example. so in general terms it gets some data, sends it to the server, and tidies up the local screen copy.
my ajax_post method is pretty complicated, but its function is to send data to the server, and process the replies.

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var row = ui.draggable.context.id;
        var data = {id:row.substr(row.lastIndexOf('_')+1),mr_id:o.mr_id,type:o.type}
        ajax_post('patients/row_remove',data);
        $('#'+row).remove();
        setup_row_banding(o.container + ' .med_row');
    } // end drop
```

Comment: Thanks mate but, this is only an Ajax help... I do not want things to be ajax-ed... I just want to implement draggable and droppable, and isolate each sections.. There is a submit button in the end.